# STM32F4 SPI Program hangs at TXE non empty

Tags: spi, stm32f4

I have been taking a udemy course on STM32F4. The course uses a different board than the one I have but from same family STM32F4. I couldn't make the SPI driver developed in the course to work in my board, so I tried t0 first test it using HAL.
I am using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg25-zU3R-E) video as a reference to communicate to L3GD20 Gyro in the development board. What I'm doing this is writing **0X11** to the **CTRL_REG1(0x20)** of the Gyroscope and then reading this register to check whether the value is written successfully or not. I could do that in HAL code

```
// ***** Spi Transmit ***** //
    // 1. Bring slave select low
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    // 2. Transmit register + data
    spiTxBuf[0] = 0x20;
    spiTxBuf[1] = 0X11;
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi5, spiTxBuf, 2, 50);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    // ***** Spi Receive ***** //
    // 1. Bring slave select low
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    // 2. Transmit register + data
    spiTxBuf[0] = 0x20 | 0x80;
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi5, spiTxBuf, 1, 50);
    // 3. Receive data
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi5, spiRxBuf, 1, 50);
    // 4. Bring slave select high
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

}
```

Above code works

But to learn the register level code I tried to create a write function

```
void SPI5_write(unsigned char data) {
    while (!(SPI5->SR & 2)) {}      /* wait until Transfer buffer Empty */
    SPI5->DR = data;                /* write data */
    while (SPI5->SR & 0x80) {}      /* wait for transmission done */
}
```

and used that to send data ([reference](http://www.microdigitaled.com/ARM/STM_ARM/Code/Ver1/Chapter08/Program8-1.txt))

```
// ***** Spi Transmit ***** //
    // 1. Bring slave select low
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    // 2. Transmit register + data
    spiTxBuf[0] = 0x20;
    spiTxBuf[1] = 0X11;
    //HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi5, spiTxBuf, 2, 50);

    SPI5_write(spiTxBuf[0]);
    SPI5_write(spiTxBuf[1]);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    // ***** Spi Receive ***** //
    // 1. Bring slave select low
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    // 2. Transmit register + data
    spiTxBuf[0] = 0x20 | 0x80;
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi5, spiTxBuf, 1, 50);
    // 3. Receive data
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi5, spiRxBuf, 1, 50);
    // 4. Bring slave select high
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

    }
```

But it's not working.
I checked using debugger. What I understand is that, it sends first byte and when *SPI5_write* called second time, it hangs at **first while loop==> TXE buffer not empty**

What causing this?

EDIT: [Complete code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q9luQJl45Moj2xWBKEe3WFpzLRfTm0zt)
IDE : KEIL MDK 5

Comment: Compare your code to the HAL's.  Also your post is missing the setup, if the SPI is not enabled and clocked the bit can never change.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have used CubeMX to generate the code. The first code shown in the post is using HAL libraries and that works. In the same file I replaced `HAL_SPI_Transmit` with transmit function. SPI and other clocks are already enabled by cubeMX. I have added link to my complete code. IDE: KEIL MDK 5

Comment: You need to compare your code to the *internal implementation* of the HAL code.  Even if it came from that cube toy, there's till source code that feeds into the compiler which you can read and compare.  When you figure out what you are doing differently than it is, you'll have the start of your solution.  The code which initializes the SPI belongs in your question, as questions here are required to stand on their own.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out the issue

SPI was enabled inside the ***HAL_SPI_Transmit()*** function. It checks wheter SPI is enabled or not inside the function, if not enabled it will enable it.

So if I want to write my own transmit function, I have to enable the corresponding SPI before transmission

eg:

```
SPI5->CR1 |=  SPI_CR1_SPE;
SPI5_write(spiTxBuf[0]);
SPI5_write(spiTxBuf[1]);
```

where

```
void SPI5_write(unsigned char data) {
    while (!(SPI5->SR & 2)) {}      /* wait until Transfer buffer Empty */
    SPI5->DR = data;                /* write data */
    while (SPI5->SR & 0x80) {}      /* wait for transmission done */
}
```